# Why does this line of Java code cause my application to quit?

Tags: java-me

Why doesn't this line of code work?

```
int display_width = display.getCurrent().getWidth();
```

When I start my midlet, I see this error: Exception. Application has unexpectedly quit. contact the application provider to resolve the issue. 0.

Why?

Comment: no current??...of course, more context would be helpful...

Comment: Verify if display.getCurrent()==null

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that something here is throwing an exception, but the library is hiding it behind that user friendly error message.

My guess is that `display.getCurrent()` is returning null, so the `getWidth()` causes a `NullPointerException`.
Try this:

```
Display myDisplay = display.getCurrent();
System.out.println(myDisplay);
int display_width = myDisplay.getWidth();
```

Note that you'll need to replace the `Display` class may whatever the type of `display.getCurrent()`'s return value is.

Or, better yet, you could try to catch the exception:

```
try {
    int display_width = display.getCurrent().getWidth();
} catch (RuntimeException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    throw e;
}
```

Comment: given the code snippet in the question, there is a chance that even `display` is null; in this case NPE could be thrown at `display.getCurrent()`

Comment: True. Either way, catching the exception would diagnose the problem.